# "defaultValue" property for <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Javascript has `textObject.defaultValue=somevalue` for retrieving the default value (stored value from page load) of an input even if you wipe the input and replace the contents, you can still get the default back. Like this:

```
// in the html page
<input id="addr1" type="text" value="21 Oak St." />

// the jquery
myInput = $("#addr1"); // the input, default value on page load = 21 Oak St.

$(myInput).val('51 New St'); // wipe default and set new

// alerts 21 Oak St
alert($(myInput).val($(myInput)[0].defaultValue));
```

**How do you accomplish this on a select?**

`selectedIndex` is boolean, not the value, so that does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `selectedIndex` is a boolean it should be an integer and as @Pointy said if you iterate the options get the defaultSelected you can set the selectedIndex to the index of the defaultSelected.

Comment: you need to use the "selected" property on the option itself you want to be the default. continue on that road.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably want to look at the "defaultSelected" attribute of "option" elements.

Initially, "defaultSelected" will be true if the original HTML of the option tag had an explicit "selected" attribute. You can change that by setting the attribute on option tags with Javascript after the page has loaded, in response to whatever conditions you like.

Answer (score 6):

This is the jquery that works for me:

```
$('select[name="name_of_select"] option[selected]').val()
```

Comment: The only issue with this is if no options have the `selected` HTML attribute set it returns undefined.  But in that case, the default value is the first option.

Answer (score 5):

with Jquery we can do sth like this :

```
$('select[name="type_id"] option').map(function()
 { 
    if($(this).attr('defaultSelected')==true) return this 
 }).get(0).value;
```

This will return the default Selected option value
:)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to loop through a forum, check their default values and their current values.

if the script comes a cross a single selectbox it will loop through the children on the selectbox.

```
oFormObject = document.forms[0];
for(i=0; i<oFormObject.elements.length; i++)
{
     oValue = oFormObject.elements[i].value;
     oType = oFormObject.elements[i].type;
     if(oType=='select-one') {
         for(k=0; k<oFormObject.elements[i].children.length; k++)
         {
             if(oFormObject.elements[i].children[k].defaultSelected==true){
                 oformElement = oFormObject.elements[i].children[k].value;
             }
         }
     }else{
         oformElement = oFormObject.elements[i].defaultValue;
     }
     console.log(oformElement);
     console.log(oValue);
     console.log(oType);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there may be multiple "selected" option elements, in that case pick the first if no other requirements are set. @Pointy tip is correct but be aware that the "defaultValue" property can be overwritten by other code in the same page. If it were read-only it would be more useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a shortest way to do this :

```
$('select#myselect').find('option[defaultSelected]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I run this on page load to manually set the defaultValue for Select boxes.

```
// Set a default value property on selectboxes (for reverting)
$('select').each(function(index,ele) {
    var origvalue = $(this).val(),
        defaultvalue = $(this).prop('defaultValue');

    // If the default value hasn't already been set for this selectbox
    if(!defaultvalue) {
        $(this).prop('defaultValue', origvalue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
$('#selectbox option').prop('selected', function() {
     return this.defaultSelected;
});
```