# javascript select input previous selection

Tags: javascript

I don't have much experience with javascript so I' not sure if/how this can be done. So I have a number of select components with a couple of options. One of these options for all of the components is "All".

Now I need to make sure that no more than one component has "All" selected. I'm using some input fields and making some validations to make sure this condition stands. However I can't see how I can do the following. When a user selects "All" from a field, and this is not allowed because there is already an "All" on the page, **put the previous selection** in it's place.

So far what I have is (component being the current select component):

```
selectedName = component.options[component.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
if (selectedName == 'All') {
  if (emptyAllSpace() == 1) {
    //here I do all the mumbo jumbo needed and assign to the hidden field the name of 
    //the component
  } 
  else {
    //Here is where I should put back the old selection value. 
  }
 }
```

Now the else branch is where I need to figure something out. So how can I / how difficult would it be to get **the selected option before the currently selected one**.

I'm also interested how difficult it would be because I could also go another route and just put as selected the first option that is not 'All' but I would rather avoid this if it's no too time consuming.

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: Also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348042/javascript-defaultvalue-property-for-use-on-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onchange event for the select. First store the default value, and reassign it on change. Or use 2 variables which keep the last 2 selected options(?).

UPDATE

Use the `onfocus` to get the value before it changes, http://jsfiddle.net/gQHqj/ .
In this handler you could register the following `onchange`, and have that value stored in the closure (onfocus's scope object).

UPDATE 2

I knew something was a bit suspicious, but didn't have time to inspect, if the user doesn't move to another element or click somewhere the element is still in focus, and the `onfocus` will not be called, while `onchange` will (if the user changes the value), with the wrong prev value. So I came up with a bugfix, you should have this structure : http://jsfiddle.net/gQHqj/4/

Comment: That piece of code is actually part of a method associated with 'onchange'. Sorry if that was not clear from the post.

Comment: Reassigning the default value on change sounds interesting. Will give it a try. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You can use `onfocus` maybe, to get the value before the select happens, haven't tried it.

Comment: Sorry for lag. Promise no more bugs/fixes :)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the previously selected value in a variable. This variable's value would be populated on form/page load and update only in case the selection is correct. Otherwise, you will revert the selection to its value.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was considering something like this but keep in mind that I have a number of select inputs. So actually I would need for N selects , N variables plus a way to associate to which select do I make the changes. Please correct me if I'm wrong of course.

Comment: You could use array(s) to keep it simple.

Comment: So you're suggestion like two arrays; one to keep the id-s of the select components and one to keep their values? Could work but still a lot of updates to those arrays would be done at each onchange event(even if 'All' is not selected). Thanks for the input so far.

Comment: Or a simple Object() will do, such as: `var mySelPrevVal = new Object(); mySelPrevVal.sel123 = '56'; console.log(mySelPrevVal.sel123);`